# Error al desplazar los valores presentes en el gráfico

Tags: r

Estoy realizando un forest plot.
Este gráfico se realiza a partir de los resultados obtenidos mediante un análisis multivariado.

El código opara realizar el forest plot es este:

```
     plot_model(glmer.1, show.values = TRUE, 
       dot.size = 0.2,
       line.size = 0.75,
       vline.color = "red",
       width = 0.2,
       sort.est = FALSE,
       digits = 1,
       vjust=2
        )
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Necesito subir los números por encima de la linea que aparece.
Lo he intentado como pueden ver con la función vjust, sin mucho éxito.
Tras modificar el valor de vjust el número se mantiene en el sitio.

¿Qué estoy realizando mal?
¿Cómo podría subir el valor?.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0):

El argumento que necesitas para modificar la posición vertical de los números no es `vjust`, sino `value.offset`. Según lo que comprobé, probablemente te baste con un valor cercano a 1 por debajo, puesto que es un argumento con bastante sensibilidad. Espero haber sido de ayuda.